# If-else condition in terraform data source

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, terraform, datasource, terraform-provider-aws

My question is very simple but unable to find any example or solution on the entire internet. I want to use the if-else condition in the `data source` of terraform and based on the value it should search the result. We have 2 different VPCs in our AWS account: 1. Prod VPC, 2. RDS VPC

Filter should work based on boolean variable var.rds_vpc

Pseudocode:

```
data "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
  if var.rds_vpc == true:
    tags = {
      Name = "rds_vpc"
      Type = "database"
    }
  else:
    tags = {
      Cluster     = "live_vpc"
      Enviornment = "production"
    }

}
```

If both VPCs could have similar tags, I could simply pass the values via variables. But in the above case, the tags are also different.

I would highly appreciate it if someone can help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are various different ways to achieve this result depending on your detailed goals. The most *direct* answer would be to use a [conditional expression](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/conditionals.html) to select one of two map values:

```
  tags = (
    var.rds_vpc ?
    {
      Name = "rds_vpc"
      Type = "database"
    } :
    {
      Cluster     = "live_vpc"
      Enviornment = "production"
    }
  )
```

If you are writing a module where its abstraction makes sense to distinguish between exactly two very different kinds of tagging structures like this then this *could* be a reasonable way to go, but a structure like this does suggest that your module might be trying to solve too many problems at once and so I'd also consider some different designs.

---

If you are just trying to write a general module that works with virtual networks, which doesn't really need to "know" what the network really represents, then you could consider making it just take arbitrary tags as an input variable and pass them through exactly as given, and then the calling module can choose those tags differently depending on its knowledge of the purpose of the VPC:

```
variables "vpc_tags" {
  type    = map(string)
}

data "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
  tags = var.vpc_tags
}
```

---

Because it seems like you are writing a module that *uses* a VPC rather than one that *manages* a VPC, you might also consider using a [dependency inversion](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/modules/develop/composition.html#dependency-inversion) approach where the module just declares that it needs a VPC but leaves it up to the calling module to decide how to provide it:

```
variables "vpc" {
  # Include here the subset of VPC attributes
  # your module actually needs.
  type = object({
    id         = string
    cidr_block = string
  })
}
```

Elsewhere in your module you can then use `var.vpc.id` in the same situations where you would otherwise have used `data.aws_vpc.vpc.id`. The *calling* module can then either use a `data "aws_vpc"` block itself *or* pass in a VPC it was already managing, depending on what's appropriate for the situation:

```
data "aws_vpc" "rds" {
  tags = {
    Name = "rds_vpc"
    Type = "database"
  }
}

module "uses_vpc" {
  source = "./uses-vpc"

  vpc = data.aws_vpc.rds
}
```

```
resource "aws_vpc" "production" {
  cidr_block = "10.1.0.0/16"

  tags = {
    Cluster     = "live_vpc"
    Enviornment = "production"
  }
}

module "uses_vpc" {
  source = "./uses-vpc"

  vpc = aws_vpc.production
}
```

This approach of using either `data "aws_vpc"` or `resource "aws_vpc"` with the same module can work because both the data resource type and the managed resource type have the `id` and `cidr_block` attributes that the variable's type constraint requires.

---

I can't know what design assumptions and constraints are most important for your system, so I can't recommend any one of these approaches in particular, but I raise them because selecting two very different values depending on a boolean variable can sometimes suggest an insufficient [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

In your case, for example, I'd worry if my overall system had a *lot* of conditions based on `var.rds_vpc` because that implies a lot of rigidity in your system design. If a later requirement calls for you to add a *third* VPC, how many different modules would you need to update to achieve that?

Premature generalization can be harmful too -- there's no need to solve problems that you don't have anywhere on the horizion -- but the two alternative patterns I've suggested above are common approaches to separation of concerns in Terraform that don't tend to lead to much additional complexity.

Comment: Though I already have solved the problem by infusing similar tags, so that I use fewer conditions and keep the code cleaner. But what you have mentioned make complete sense and should be used to resolve such problems. Hence, accepting this ans for people having the same issue.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it with count statement and ternary operator combination.

```
data "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
    tags = {
      Name = "rds_vpc"
      Type = "database"
    }
    count = var.rds_vpc == true ? 1 : 0
}
data "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
    tags = {
      Cluster     = "live_vpc"
      Enviornment = "production"
    }
    count = var.rds_vpc == true ? 0 : 1
}
```

you can pass tags to resource like this maybe.

```
variable tag_x {
    type = map(string)
}

variable tag_y {
    type = map(string)
}

tag_x = {
    Name = "rds_vpc"
    Type = "database"
}

tag_y = {
      Cluster     = "live_vpc"
      Enviornment = "production"
}

data "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
    tags = var.rds_vpc == true ? var.tag_x : var.tag_y
}
```

Comment: I appreciate what you are suggesting and I wish this could work. I have tried this already but terraform does not allow having 2 data sources with the same name:
`A aws_vpc data resource named "vpc" was already declared`. If I create data source with diff name, then I've to create resources also with different names and pass data values there. In nutshell, I have to create whole different new module because of this small change if I go by this way. 

Anyway, thanks for your answer. I think I can rename the tags at aws side to make it work.

Comment: What frustrating is, such conditions are the basics of each language. They can simply allow conditions to be used and literally, this will help to reduce the code size up to a greater extent. we do not have to duplicate the code at all.

Comment: Because if you have different resources for different envs, for example test/stage/prod, you should create new folder structrue for each env. Do not try to use conditions even if you can with workarounds. Thats not maintable.

Answer (score 3):

```
data "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
  tags =
    var.rds_vpc == true ? "Name" : "Cluster" = var.rds_vpc == true ? "rds_vpc"  : "live_vpc"
    var.rds_vpc == true ? "Type" : "Environment" = var.rds_vpc == true ? "database" : "production"
  }
}
```

Comment: For that, both tags should be similar, as you have mentioned `Name` and `Type`

Comment: Oh, I missed that. My apologies